# Responsive Grid Layout with background image

Tags: html, wordpress, css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I want to make grid layout with images as background.I want 2 column and 2 row grid but with different heights and widths. It should be responsive and when we resize the window or screen, the grid and the images should resize proportionally. How can i do this? Please help me. Here is my code.

```css
#ser_wrap{
 margin: auto;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 0;
}

#col1{
 background: url(images/col1.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0 #CC8F1D;
 background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 35vh;
 padding: 0;
}

#col2{
 background: url(images/col2.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0 #BA7677;
 background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 45vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ser_wrap" class="col-lg-12">
     <div id="col1" class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
         
        </div>
        <div id="col2" class="col-md-7 col-lg-7">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have an attempt at code thats not working?

Comment: @zedd.. I have added my code now.

Comment: and what is the unwanted behaviour with the code you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you expect the result is as follows:

```css
#ser_wrap{
 margin: auto;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 0;
}

#col1{
 background: url(http://www.sonoravirtual.com/images/events/big/304946bde31e3ad3853a70a02b97e1d4.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0 #CC8F1D;
 background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 35vh;
 padding: 0;
}

#col2{
 background: url(http://www.sonoravirtual.com/images/events/big/304946bde31e3ad3853a70a02b97e1d4.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0 #BA7677;
 background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 45vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ser_wrap" class="col-lg-12">
     <div id="col1" class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <!-- <img src="http://www.sonoravirtual.com/images/events/big/304946bde31e3ad3853a70a02b97e1d4.jpg" class="img-responsive"> -->
        </div>
        <div id="col2" class="col-md-7 col-lg-7">
        <!-- <img src="http://www.sonoravirtual.com/images/events/big/304946bde31e3ad3853a70a02b97e1d4.jpg" class="img-responsive"> -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Use the "img-resposive" class included in bootstrap framework in "img" tags.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is it good to use the img tag instead of background image? How can i fill the container with the image while using img tag?

Comment: Update the code: Comments the tags "img" as to disable and modified the css so that images are displayed as background in divs. I suggest you use the tag "img". If you use pictures of different heights as background, need to assign fixed heights to the div container. Otherwise the height is adjusted to the dimensions of the image proportionally (using the tag "img").

Comment: Thank you so much. Its Perfect

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the 2 column/2 row dilemma can be solved by using table/tr/td. The background for these can be easily changed if you want images by putting them in the background tag in the CSS, which you've already done. Here's a quick JSfiddle to show what I mean. I realise this isn't the most elegant solution, but it's quick :)

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ser_wrap" class="col-lg-12">
   <table cellpadding=4>
        <tr colspan = 2>
            <td id="col1"></td>
            <td id = "col3"></td>         
        </tr>
        <tr colspan = 2>
            <td id="col2"></td>
            <td id = "col4"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and then the CSS

```
#ser_wrap{
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0;

}

#col1{
    background: url(images/col1.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0 #CC8F1D;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    min-height: 35vh;
    padding: 0;

}

#col2{
    background: url(images/col2.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0 #BA7677;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    min-height: 45vh;
}

#col3{
    background: black;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    min-height: 45vh;
}

#col4{
    background: red;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    min-height: 45vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wwgco40v/2/